# Trying to get invalid-feedback working in bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4

Here is some form code where I want to engage the invalid-feedback class in bootstrap

```
<form class="needs-validation" action="submit_gene_entry.php" method="post">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-check">
          <label for=chromosome_postvar>Chromosome</label>
          <input name=chromosome_postvar type=text pattern="[IVX]{1,3}" required class="form-control" placeholder="associated chromosome">
          <div class="invalid-feedback">
              Valid numbers for a chromosome designation are required.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
        <button type=submit class="btn btn-primary">Accept Gene Entry</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

The text field has a pattern associated with it. When I click submit, if the valid is illegal, the browser won't proceed, and it puts up a popup telling the user to please match the requested format. The invalid feedback message is never engaged.

I've been playing around with various tags to trigger it, form-check and form-group, but they make no difference, nor is it really clear what they actually do, anyway.

Interestingly, if I give the affected field a title, that title appears in the rejection message, so it's like the browser is separately doing the rejection and bootstrap classes are being ignored entirely.

You can see the code at https://jsfiddle.net/mauricev/a95vf0oq/2/

Comment: "if the valid is illegal" should read "if the entered data in the field is illegal".